# Use CUPS own driver when sharing a printer

Tags: linux, drivers, printer, cups

I am trying to get an old printer working for a family member. The printer itself is working fine but I can't find a way to print from Windows 10 to that printer, the drivers for that printer no longer support the most modern versions of Windows.

Luckily, I was able to print to that printer using Ubuntu and I shared the printer using the GUI. The Windows machine was able to see it but still asked me for a driver before being able to print to it.

From what I just read (correct me if I'm wrong), Ubuntu use CUPS by default for printing, and CUPS should use its own driver when sharing, which was apparently not the case. Am I missing something ?

Just a little note: I will eventually use a Raspberry Pi for this (I have none that I can use right now), so if there something I might need to know that will be different on a Pi (else then the GUI), please let me know!

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, this is a USB printer.

Comment: What model is the printer? If it is an old dot matrix it will support plain ASCII text, and the Generic/Text Only driver will work. If it supports PCL5, try a LaserJet4 driver (and the G/TO driver will also work).

Comment: This is the printer: https://epson.com/For-Home/Printers/Photo/Epson-Stylus-Photo-960-Ink-Jet-Printer/p/C11C456021 . So I should try the LaserJet4 driver on Windows?

Comment: Can you print with Linux? The key here is whether or not the printer was added to CUPS using the “raw” driver.

Comment: @DanielB, do you want to know if I can print from a Linux computer directly connected to the printer via USB (which I can), or do you want to know if another Linux machine can print via the shared printer ?

Comment: The important thing is that the print server (the machine that’s directly connected to the printer over USB) can print. You said it can, so that’s great. It means Windows can use a generic PostScript driver to print. I’ll add an answer later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can print on Linux, you have a proper driver. This is important because CUPS also supports “raw” queues where it does not actually know how to create printer data itself but relies on client-side drivers to do that.

Because CUPS knows how to print, you can just feed it PostScript data. Windows ships with various suitable drivers. They need not be related to your printer in any way.

I’ll quote [Arch Wiki’s Printer sharing article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Printer_sharing#Linux_server_-_Windows_client) on the following.

First, to enable sharing, it refers to the CUPS server:

> Open up the web interface to the server, select the Administration tab, look under the Server heading, and enable the "Share printers connected to this system" option. Save your change by clicking on the Change Settings button. The server will automatically restart.

Then, to install the printer on Windows:

> #### Sharing via IPP
>
> The preferred way to connect a Windows client to a Linux print server is using IPP, as the configuration is simpler than using Samba. It is a standard printer protocol based on HTTP, allowing you to use port forwarding, tunneling etc. IPP has been natively supported by Windows since Windows 2000.
>
> > **Note:** You may have to add the Internet Printing Client to Windows (*Control Panel->Programs->Turn Windows features on or off->Print and Document Services*)
>
> [...]
>
> On the Windows computer, go to *Control Panel->Devices and Printers* and choose 'Add a printer'. If on Windows 10, click "The printer that I want isn't listed". Next, choose 'Select a shared printer by name' and type in the location of the printer:
>
> ```
> http://hostname:631/printers/printer_name
> ```
>
> (where *hostname* is the GNU/Linux server's hostname or IP address and *printer_name* is the name of the print queue being connected to. [...]
>
> **Note:**
>
> > - The 'Add Printer' dialog in Windows suggests the format `http://computername/printers/printername/.printer`, which it will not accept. Instead, use the syntax suggested above.
> > - If you are using a proxy carefully check any used proxy **exclusions**. A wrong setting here may result in you being unable to add a printer until the next reboot even if you disable the proxy afterwards (at least on Windows 7).
>
> After this, install the native printer drivers for your printer on the Windows computer. **If the CUPS server's print queue is set up to use its own printer drivers instead of as a `raw` queue, you can just select a generic postscript printer driver for the Windows client** (e.g. 'HP Color LaserJet 8500 PS' or 'Xerox DocuTech 135 PS2').

(Emphasis in last paragraph mine).

Comment: This works for me, but the paper format is wrong: I have created a virtual tea4cups printer in Linux with "$ sudo lpadmin -p pretendq -v tea4cups:/socket://192.168.7.200:9100 -E -P /etc/cups/ppd/MyRealPrinter.ppd". So with your method I get a *.ps file in the path "/var/spool/cups/". But when I open it, I can see, that it has the wrong format. It should be A4. But it is US letter although my printer setting is set to A4. Also my virtual tea4cups printer is set to A4. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Isn't it more or less up to the application creating the printer data?

Answer (score 2):

Your printer, the Epson Stylus Photo 960 supports ESC/P so it should support text printing. It does not support PCL5. One Windows 10 driver that will work with it is the Generic/Text Only driver. Note that this driver is true to label: it prints *text only*.

If you need to print graphics, or you just need more control over the printer, you can try using a driver for another ESC/P printer. If you search for "windows 10 esc/p driver" you will find a number of them. Most appear to be for printers in the Epson LX and FX ranges. These are dot-matrix printers, which do not support colour. Pick one for a printer that has similar capabilities as yours, e.g. the [LQ-1070](http://www.driverfiles.net/Printers/Epson/epson-LQ-1070-ESC-P2/download/page,sh,24190,154,12,.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that driver as soon as I can and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried to use another driver but for some reason this is not working. Anyway, Daniel B answer solved my problem.

Comment: You helped for solve getting an old HP 1012 back into service on Windows 10. Shared out via CUPS. I simply made it use the Microsoft Generic Postscript driver and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it working by cobbling together a few pieces.

I'm new here and don't have the reputation to comment on (or even upvote) other answers.  I understand why.  I wish we could have nice things.

Daniel B's answer is great.  Unfortunately it took me a while to figure out some things to make it work.  Here's what I wish I knew the first time I read his answer when I was trying to print on an old old Samsung ML-1740 printer via CUPS.  These weren't obvious to me.

- My printer is way past end-of-life.  Samsung sold their printer biz to HP who explicitly listed my printer as not supported in win10.  I was able to get it working connected locally via USB by finding/installing an old Samsung Universal Printer Driver v2 in winXP compatibility mode.
- Setting up a RAW queue in CUPS didn't work with the driver setup that worked with the same printer when connected via local USB.
- Now to try CUPS with a driver but couldn't find my model number among those listed.
- I made a PPD printer driver for old printer at openprinting https://www.openprinting.org/driver/gdi/ and used it when adding the printer to CUPS.
- I had a difficult time finding any/generic postscript printer drivers on my system - as directed by the openprinting page and this page.  There is mention of Adobe and Microsoft generic drivers but I couldn't find them.
- I used HP Universal Print Driver for Windows - Postscript found here https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-universal-print-driver-series-for-windows/503548/model/503550
- Adding it from HP's installation program didn't work right.  I added samba print sharing https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/ and browsed it by using the explorer location/url (sample IPv4 address) \192.168.1.11 - then right-clicked and selected "connect" - used the HP driver when prompted.

That took me entirely way too long.  I'm sharing it here in case I wasn't the cause of the delays.