# Sharing a printer on Arch to Windows clients

Tags: printer, network-shares, arch-linux, samba, cups

Following the stereotype that printers never "just work", I need help with sharing my Samsung ML-2160 on Arch.

I already followed some guides, installed CUPS and the samsung-unified-driver package. I got the printer to work with CUPS and I can print the test page without any problems. However the problems start when I want to share my printer to a Windows client. I tried Samba first ([Here is the config](https://pastebin.com/A8WGZhuE)). I tried adding the printer like so:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYbqU.jpg)

It than prompts me for a driver, I select my printer model

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBkbS.jpg)

Press OK, and I can see the printer in the control panel

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoRel.jpg)

HOWEVER when I try to print anything with it, nothing happens. Not even any errors, it just doesn't print or do anything.

Next I tried [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/1234686/use-cups-own-driver-when-sharing-a-printer), connecting via IPP. Followed every step precisely, but the same thing happens as before.

I tried setting the printer make/model to raw in CUPS too, but that didn't work either.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnJcl.jpg)

So this is where I am right now. I can print the CUPS test page with these settings, but I cannot use the shared printer.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnJcl.jpg)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171350/adding-cups-shared-printers-to-windows-client

Comment: When you try to print from windows, do you see the print job in the CUPS queue? You may need to click on "show all jobs"

Comment: it does not show up in the cups queue, and it doesn't even show up in the windows queue